# Object.<anonymous>...Module not found

Tags: node.js, ejs

The below is what's in my current file(s). Being absolutely new to this field understanding documentation is key. However, I can't see what i missed as to why the "Module Not Found" error would be thrown. What am I missing?

my date.js code file:

```
console.log(module);

function getDate() {

  let today = new Date();

  let options = {
    weekday: "long",
    day: "number",
    month: "long",
  };

  let day = today.toLocaleDateString("en-US", options);
  return day;
}
```

my required request in my app.js file:

```
const date = require(__dirname + "/date.js");
```

I also installed $npm install request and still threw a bug

Comment: did you export the function

Comment: How do you call this file?

And is it full of `date.js` content, what happens with tag `EJS`

Comment: @Rkv88-Kanyan when i attempted to export is when the "Module Not Found" was thrown on the local server.

Comment: @Hongarc that's a fair question i can't answer at the moment. I will have to try it again when i get in from visiting a client tomorrow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On line 1, you're logging a variable called `module`. This variable doesn't exist – which I think is what the error is? Remove line 1 and run again.

Or to demonstrate my point, try adding this to line 1:

```js
const module = 'something';
console.log(module);
```

You should see 'something' logged instead of the error.

**Side note:**

You can require a module without using `__dirname` like so:

`const date = require("./date.js");` where `./` is the same as `__dirname` (same directory as the file you called the require function in)

Comment: This is a `Node.js` question, `module` is defined.

Comment: @Andy thank you. I still haven't linked my email for stackoverflow to my phone or laptop. I forgot to come back and reply "Yes. This worked."

Comment: @hong4rc yes. I do have a date.js file